# how do i correctly output the number of entrys in a grid that have passed in reading order using only x and y positions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, math

```js
var len = 5
var wid = 5
var g = "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa";

for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < wid; y++) {
    var yC = x % len
    var xC = Math.floor(x / len)
    console.log(x + y * xC)
  }
}
```

this code is just a mockup of what im trying to do. currently, if you were to check the console after running this, it would log the numbers 0-4 5 times each, but what i am trying to do i output the numbers 0-24 1 time each.

note that i cant simply just loop the length of the string and output the current character index as i need to use the x and y for something else that is not present here.

https://jsfiddle.net/g19bmnsh/

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: isn't `(x * len) + y` enough for you?

Comment: @TahaPaksu that outputs the numbers in the wrong order

Comment: How come? do you want to count it down like 24 to 0?

Comment: @TahaPaksu no it was just that without the brackets it does something entirely different, and i didnt catch your edit soon enough, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

```js
var len = 5
var wid = 5
var g = "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa" +
  "aaaaa";

for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < wid; y++) {
    var yC = x % len
    var xC = Math.floor(x / len)
    console.log("x: " + x, "y: " + y, "k: " + (x + y * xC), "i:" + (y + (x * len)))
  }
}
```